# Reach out to Coinbase

Tags: support, outsourcing

Coinbase, a cryptocurrency trading platform, has an API. The documentation page for their API, https://developers.coinbase.com/, has a support link that redirects to Stack Overflow:

[image]

This causes questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905371/need-full-information-for-api-integration-of-coinbase to be dumped here by people who haven't read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) nor [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Deleted question:

[image]

Can someone contact them to explain that this isn't how it works?

Comment: To me this looks like Coinbase wants to save money for not building their own help forum.

Comment: Also they have it linked directly (no hover-over thing) at the bottom of the page: https://imgur.com/5nVgBa2

Comment: @chade_ nothing wrong with that, so long as they follow SO's rules, right.

Comment: Perhaps they should move to another SE community? There's bitcoin and ethereum.

Comment: @boysimpledimple those sites are for questions about the cryptocurrency, while here it is about an API (in line with SOs rules - while asked correctly)

Comment: Apparently Skype is doing this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893979/skype-interface-on-high-sierra-too-big-for-screen?noredirect=1#comment82757709_47893979

Comment: For whatever reason, we have seen similar behavior from a variety of organizations in the past.  There's nothing inherently wrong with it, but it tends not to work out well, because *Stack Overflow is not a help site*.  These days, perhaps this sort of thing would be a good use of Channels.

Comment: It's a pity the white labeled SO didn't take off. Would've been nice to say "go pay for a SO instance".

Comment: FYI Coinbase are under a massive load right now due to Bitcoin being in the news, and even before that a support ticket was taking multiple weeks to answer. They've also just added another cryptocurrency to their portfolio which has added even more traffic. Don't expect them to response, let alone care about it!

Comment: @Liam: Skype list SO together with two other pages as community resources. Coinbase says "please explore and contact us through our dev support channels" and lists SO there. Skype sounds to me like a list of relevant links while Coinbase actively redirects user here to get support from the company

Comment: @BDL Ah okay, I wasn't able to find where Skype was directing people. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Liam it's in the footer of this page: https://dev.office.com/Skype

Comment: @BDL that's not even Skype - it's Microsoft Office in general

Comment: @TankorSmash well unfortunately, a massive majority of such questions do not follow SO rules/policy.  Closing/deleting them requires effort that is then not spent on answering good questions.  It's an attempt by companies to demostrate that they provide support, but offload the cost to SO.  It's great for them - they can say that they provide support, they don't have to pay for any support, SO user-moderators put in the time to close the bad questions and then get blamed for not helping.  Yes, it is wrong!

Comment: @MartinJames It varies. Some organisations have links that explain what's on topic here, actively monitor the relevant tags, and ensure that the result benefits both SO and their own organisation. Encouraging this good version is [official policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). Others, admittedly, just send people here when they don't have time to talk to them, in the hope that someone else will deal with it.

Comment: I'm heavily involved in the Bitcoin space, and I can tell you right here and now: Good luck trying to get a timely, proper, response from Coinbase. They're too slammed to keep up; their site traffic is so intense, they can hardly keep their website up. This is the least of their worries, we're just gonna have to deal with the traffic and kill bad questions. This isn't ideal, but I'm just stating the facts.

Comment: I have a better idea: `if (referer.startsWith("https://coinbase.com")) exit(404);`

Comment: When you thought their insider trading that caused the whole crypto market to crash today wasn't bad enough.

Comment: I almost feel bad for the people posting question, only putting the "coinbase" tag on them and then seeing their questions go unnoticed because they do not know how this site and tags and everything works...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I contacted their customer support system, but it seems as if they are going to take several days to respond. I'm poking around to see if I can contact someone working on the API, which is probably going to be more effective at getting the site fixed in any case.

In the meantime, I've tried to make [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coinbase/info) a little more clear:

> Note: this tag is for questions about the Coinbase API for buying, selling, storing, and transferring digital currency. Please do not ask general support questions here.

I'll edit this answer if I get any response from Coinbase.

Comment: Is my very biased point of view that changing the name of the tag is way more effective than the tag wiki, as it's more discoverable and inmediatelly obvious.

Comment: @Braiam: Good point. I move those questions to [tag:coinbase-api] and made [coinbase a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coinbase-api/synonyms).

Comment: Can we get [gdax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdax) renamed to `gdax-api` as well? GDAX is the exchange owned by Coinbase, and is seeing an explosion of questions as well.

Comment: @RyanZim: Sure thing. Maybe you could [add a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/127871)?

Comment: I think they're going under at the moment with the amount of activity on their network, so I wouldn't expect a response any time soon...

Comment: @JonEricson Added the tag wiki; it's awaiting peer review since I don't have enough rep to edit directly.

Comment: Thanks,  @RyanZim. I approved it.

Comment: It'd be fun and payback if you set the servers to "Rick Roll" visitors with an HTTP `Referer` of coinbase.com.

Comment: Send them a seize and desist letter. That should get the ball rolling.

Comment: @dan-klasson: Right now there are 211 extant [tag:coinbase-api] questions and 23 deleted questions. Even if every one of those is complete garbage, that's not an unmanageable problem. Let's not overreact here.

Comment: @JonEricson Did you ever got a response from Coinbase since you contacted them?

Comment: @chade_: I have not. Looks like we are still getting questions, but not a ton.

Answer (score 19):

There is a canonical help page for this, as it is a fairly common occurrence: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support It sets out what we expect from third parties who want to link to us in this way, to ensure that everyone gets a positive experience.

I suggest politely (Assume Good Faith) linking to this in comments on any off-topic / low quality questions which seem to have come from this route; if Coinbase staff *are* monitoring the tag, this will help bring it to their attention.

If they are *not* monitoring the tag, someone will need to contact them a different way. In my view, it would be fine for this to be from any member of the community, but we don't want to flood them with e-mails (again, assuming good faith), so post an answer here if you have done / are planning to do this.

If they don't respond, or don't provide a reasonable means of contact, then it would be appropriate for Stack Overflow Community staff to try to find more official channels.

Comment: Is treating these question as any other bad? Why do we need to go against net neutrality and treat asker based on their referer?

Comment: @Basilevs Absolutely, we should not treat them any more harshly; but we also shouldn't treat them any more leniently. Often, the questions are obviously off-topic, but the asker says "but company X sent me here". We shouldn't accept that as justification to bend the rules, but the asker is not the one at fault if they have been misled by a third party. Hence my emphasis on hoping the *third party* will see the comment, "on any *off-topic / low quality* questions which seem to have come from this route". If the link only leads to high-quality, on-topic questions, there's no problem.